# Can I use "vice versa" phrase in this case?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Can I use it in this case?

Example:

> The weather is awesome! But what if vice versa?

I think that this phrase means: "the weather is awesome, but what if weather will be bad?".

Is is possible to use "vice versa" this way?

Comment: As Barmer's answer indicates, "The weather is awesome! But what if vice versa?" suggests the relational reversal, "The awesome is weather," which doesn't make sense in English.

Comment: You want some word that is appropriate for 'weather' and somewhat opposite of 'awesome' -- the weather is awesome now; but what if it were *terrible?* (we have recently had some [terrible weather here...](https://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/ShowTopic-g608516-i10783-k3964686-Terrible_weather_forecast-Kuramathi.html.) (2)  [and here!](https://www.tripadvisor.co.za/ShowTopic-g311415-i869-k7286188-Terrible_weather-Bora_Bora_Society_Islands.html))

Answer (score 3):

No, "vice versa" can't be used like this. It doesn't just mean the opposite. It's used when you're describing an ordered relationship between two things, and refers to the relationship in the opposite order.

From [dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/vice-versa?s=t)

> in reverse order from the way something has been stated; the other way around: 
> *She dislikes me, and vice versa.*
>   *Copernicus was the first to suggest that the earth revolves around the sun, and not vice versa.*

There's no ordering in your statement *The weather is awesome!*, so there's nothing to reverse.

You could use it in something like this:

> The weather went from miserable to awesome yesterday. Today it was vice versa.

meaning that today the weather started awesome and ended miserable.

Comment: Okay, thank you! But what I can use to correctly explain what I want?

Comment: "But what if it was not?" or "But what if it was otherwise?"